# How to translate pivot values with laravel-translatable?

Tags: laravel, translation

I just started using [laravel-translatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable)  package from dimsav which enables to set and retrieve translated strings from the database using Eloquent models. It works great but I still have trouble translating pivot values from belongsToMany relationships.

I have a model called Combination defined as shown below:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Combination extends Model {
   public function product() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
   }

   public function product_attributes() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Attribute')->withPivot('value');
   }
}
```

Here is my Attribute model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

class Attribute extends Model {
   use Translatable;

   public $translatedAttributes = ['name'];
}

class AttributeTranslation extends Model {
   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

For instance, I have a Product called "T-Shirt" with two Attributes:

1. *Color*
2. *Size*

This Product has two combinations:

1. *Black / M*
2. *Black / L*

These values are stored as pivot values in an intermediate table called attribute_combination like this:

```
+--------------+----------------+-------+ 
| attribute_id | combination_id | value |
|--------------+----------------+-------|
| 1            | 1              | Black |
| 2            | 1              | M     |
| 1            | 2              | Black |
| 2            | 2              | L     |
+--------------+----------------+-------+
```

I have no problem retrieving the translated attribute's name using `$attribute->name` but I can't find a way to retrieve the translated pivot values. I tried to create a table called attribute_combination_translations and its AttributeCombination model as shown below but it does not work.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

class AttributeCombination extends Model {
   use Translatable;

   protected $table = 'attribute_combination';
   public $translatedAttributes = ['value'];
}

class AttributeCombinationTranslation extends Model {
   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $fillable = ['value'];
}
```

Maybe anyone using this package could help me get through this?

Comment: Did you have any success with this? I have managed to persist pivot table translations but there is a workaround

Comment: @SlavisaPerisic I found a workaround but I had to change a bit my code to make it work. I just wrote a AttributeCombination model with custom relationships with Attribute and Combination and I don't use pivot anymore https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable/issues/303